# Data manipulation with MySQL - join and counting

Tags: python, mysql, relational-database

**Outline:** I have two tables - one with a dictionary of authors and books, and another with some comparisons between books of different authors.

```
Book_id(PK)    Author               Book_id_1(CPK)   Book_id_2(CPK)    Book_similarity
=====================               ==================================================
1              Amy                  1                3                 High
2              Amy                  1                4                 Low
3              Ben                  2                3                 High
4              Ben                  2                4                 High
                                    3                1                 High
                                    3                2                 High
                                    4                1                 Low
                                    4                2                 High
```

**Problem:** I'm trying to make a query where it returns the table below, counting the number of 'high' and 'low' similarities found - this traces the books back to the authors that wrote them.

```
Author_1(CPK)     Author_2(CPK)   Num_high   Num_low
====================================================
Amy               Ben             3          1
Ben               Amy             3          1
```

I realise there is overlap in the final table, but it's the only way I can make it so that there's one column which is searchable. I suspect I have to use two queries to generate the outcome and a join somewhere, but I'm still pretty new to MySQL.

**NB:** Using python and MySQLdb, if that's going to be of use. Otherwise, I'll just plug the query into the python cur.execute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not really clear, but I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT b1.Author AS Author_1, b2.Author AS Author_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.Book_similarity = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Num_high,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.Book_similarity = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Num_low
FROM similarity s
INNER JOIN book b1 ON b1.book_id = s.book_id_1
INNER JOIN book b2 ON b2.book_id = s.book_id_2
GROUP BY b1.Author, b2.Author
```

Basically, you just have to join the book table on both book_id in similarity table (so you can access the author of books in book_id_1 and book_id_2), and then count 1 each time the similarity is low for Num_low, and the same for Num_high (when high similarity of course).

Comment: genius! Thanks so much. I think the `a1` and `a2` should be `b1` and `b2`, btw. Sorry the question was a little unclear. Do you mind giving a brief explanation of what this query does?

Comment: I added some explanations. I don't know if it's clear, but the query seems quite self-explanatory, I don't know what to add that wouldn't paraphrase the query (I feel I already did that).

Comment: I think it's the joins that I don't understand properly - don't worry I'll go and do some digging for a tutorial or something :). Thanks for your help!